# PHP : How to sort left to right php before reading

Tags: php

The code below is working in reading per row and count each identical appearances. However, I still need excel to sort per row left to right before I i save it as delimited by as text file. Right now I want to omit the excel step. I checked on php manual and saw the sort and explode functions. I inserted those command but its not working. Can someone help me point to the right direction ?

raw data is :

```
hero2,hero1,hero3
hero2,hero3,hero4
hero1,hero2,hero3
```

text file db after excel :

```
hero1,hero2,hero3
hero2,hero3,hero4
hero1,hero2,hero3
```

output :

```
appeared 2x: hero1,hero2,hero3
apprered 1x: hero2,hero3,hero4
```

Code :

```
<?php

$data = file("heroes.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines = explode(",", $data);
$sort ($lines);
$result = array_count_values($lines);

foreach($result as $v => $amount)
    echo "Appeared " . $amount . "x: " . $v . "<br />";

?>
```

After reading the suggestions and samples of those who answered  I came up with this code now.

```
 <?php

 $data = file("heroes.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
 $lines = explode(",", implode($data));
 $sorted_lines = sort($lines); // sorted data
 $result = array_count_values($lines);

 // output the sorted data
 foreach($result  as $v => $amount) {
 echo "Appeared " . $amount . "x: " . $v . "\n";
 }

 ?>
```

however the ouput became like this

output :

```
appeared 3x: hero2
appeared 3x: hero3
appeared 2x: hero1
appeared 1x: hero4
```

correct output should be like this

```
output :

appeared 2x: hero1,hero2,hero3
apprered 1x: hero2,hero3,hero4
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is you are using explode with a space and you should be using it with a comma. `explode(",",$data);`

I'm thinking you then also want to turn your data back into a string before you try and count them or I don't think you'll get the results you're expecting.

For example...

```
$sortedString = implode(",", $theArray);
```

Comment: Did the OP edit the question code after you answered or you saw the call to `explode()` the wrong way?

Comment: It was edited when I saw it but maybe you already reply it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the old data before doing the sort. And you are not using a PHP function `sort`, you are instead making it a kind of a variable (remove the $ before it).

```
<?php

$data = file("heroes.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines = explode(",", $data);
$sorted_lines = sort($lines); // sorted data
$result = array_count_values($sorted_lines);

// output the sorted data
foreach($result  as $v => $amount) {
    echo "Appeared " . $amount . "x: " . $v . "<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Good catch on the $sort @Dadani